# Create Batch file to execute multiple batch files and VBS files

Tags: batch, vbscript

I have multiple batch files and vbs files , when i try to create a batch to call them it stop after the last batch file and dont execute the vbs.

without giving any error

if i put the vbs at the start it execute it alone.

any advice ?

```
@echo off 
call batch1.bat 
call batch2.bat 
cscript //nologo test.vbs
```

Comment: Try to post your batch file (the one that calls) all of the others

Comment: @echo off
call batch1.bat
call batch2.bat
cscript //nologo test.vbs

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the call commands and moving the //nologo to after the test.vbs so it will look like this. That is mostly a personal taste change but I have a couple of Batch files that call multiple batch and vbs files and have never had an issue. If that doesn't work, my only guess is that something is wrong with the environment.

```
@echo off 

batch1.bat

batch2.bat

cscript test.vbs  //nologo
```